# Django Heroku deployment URLconf error. Page not found (404)

Tags: django, url, heroku

I am a newbie to Django and trying to deploy my Django app on Heroku. I followed a tutorial and did everything, but when I was finally ready to deploy my app, I get the error "Page not found."

I have tried removing the include() around my admin.site.urls because it worked for someone else, but it didn't work for me.

this is my urls.py file:

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path, include
 from django.conf import settings
 from django.conf.urls.static import static
 from profiles.views import delete



 urlpatterns = [
 path(r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),
 path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

this is my settings.py file:

```
import os
import django_heroku
import django
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'firstDjango.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application 

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


SECRET_KEY="bb33e5a618aa4f6e549b8207ad1d8fa7cd8d1015e13c8780"

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ewuradjango.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

 INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',

#third party

#own 
# 'pages'
'profiles',
 ]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 ]

 ROOT_URLCONF = 'firstDjango.urls'

 TEMPLATES = [
 {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'firstDjango.wsgi.application'



 DATABASES = {
   'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',

     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),

 }
}




AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
  {
    'NAME':         'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
  },
]



 LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

 TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

 USE_I18N = True

 USE_L10N = True

 USE_TZ = True




 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
 ]

 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
 STATIC_TMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


 MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

 django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

This is the verbose error:

```
 Page not found (404)
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   https://ewuradjango.herokuapp.com/
 Using the URLconf defined in firstDjango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
 ^profiles/
 ^admin/
 ^media/(?P<path>.*)$
 The empty path didn't match any of these.
 You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a      standard 404 page.
```

Comment: Did you try this locally before deploying? As the error says, you haven't got a path for the root page, so this wouldn't work anywhere; your problem has nothing to do with Heroku.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks. I have got it now. the problem was the root path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you haven't got a route set up for your root path '/'. Try accessing https://ewuradjango.herokuapp.com/admin or https://ewuradjango.herokuapp.com/profiles as you've got paths for them set up in your first code block.

To add a root path try something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

which should direct your root path to your admin page.

Comment: Thanks. I have got it now. That was the problem @StevensQiu